# Having PHP Error Log in IIS Log - One for each site

Tags: php, iis, log-files

I am currently trying to do as I was doing in `apache`: setting a different PHP Error Log for every application. I read a few tutorial so far and none seems to explain exactly what I want and I cannot believe IIS administrator are not using it since it is a basic and very useful feature.

First of all, I did set these specification in my php.ini file:

```
log_errors = On
error_log = syslog
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Then, in IIS, in the «Logs» option of my Website, I selected the W3C Format, selected the option «One file per site», select «LOG File and ETW Events» and set the task to create a new file every day. I created a bug (by purpose) on my website (causing a 500 error) but it doesn't seem to keep it in the log. I can see in the log that a user went on the page and had an error 500, but the error is not reported...

Is this even possible using IIS? If so, how?

PS: I do not care to have a separate log for every website containing only the PHP Error(s), or every error linked in one site (that wouldn't bother me either).

PPS: I know error_log could be a path to one file, but I'd really want each site to have their individual error log...

Thank you, a lot and have a good day.

Comment: Had a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14396282/503621

Comment: @bshea no sadly my error are logging, but they are logging all the error of all my site at the same place... (C:\Windows\Temp\PHP56ErrorLog.txt) (not sure about the file name but it's something like this). Under apache, it was very easy for me in the Website configuration (or even in the .htaccess if I wanted) to specify a log that is specific for the events happening on a website, and another one for the error happening. Under IIS, I can have separated event log, but it seems impossible for the error log.